# Dynamic Property Binding in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Apparently, the same columns value-type differs across environments for the same database entity (table) & they refuse to update to a common type - don't ask why!

I am using Entity Framework (version 6.1.3) alongside a Unit of Work for data-access.  And, as you can guess, I am getting errors because the DEV & the QA database definitions do not match for the same column.

**THE GOOD NEWS:**
We do not save into these particular tables - we only query those particular tables.

SAMPLE MODEL:
There are obviously more columns than this.

```
public partial class Transactions
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    public float Amount { get; set; } //<-- This type differs between database environments
}
```

**MY QUESTION:**

- Is there a way to dynamically bind the value for a column in Entity Framework?
- Or, can I treat it as a dynamic under-the-hood...and transform it to an expected type which is constant to my model?

OPTIMALLY - AND TO BE CLEAR:
I would like to define the property concretely, and have Entity Framework "convert" from the unknown type & into the concrete type - but under-the-hood.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is just one of MANY problems you're going to face by trying to support different types with the same codebase.  That said, you could try defining the EF type as `string` and see if it "magically" converts the various source types to a string representation.  Either that or a config parameter that lets you choose between two different SQL statements that coalecse to a common type.

Comment: You could make the class generic and have multiple context objects that define different types?

Comment: If you only query it- maybe add views with casts and coverts and query those views instead?

Comment: I agree...I "could" create different concrete DBCONTEXT's by-environment.  I am "hoping" to be able to use OnModelCreating or something under-the-hood of the DBCONTEXT to query meta-data somehow and "bind" to the concretely expected type.

Comment: I would use a tool like Dapper to read the data into dynamic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the types of the columns are compatible (i.e. are all numbers) you can have a common type on the class then disable model checking (and migration). This solution could work on some DBMSs and not on some Others (depends on the provider).

You can write a view with cast and map it in your model (and not the table).

You can write a direct query with EF (official docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx similar to Dapper solution with same advantages and defects, in your case lazy load won't work).

Comment: FOR THOSE INTERESTED: I ended-up writing a CAST MAP in a separate view USING SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY and bound to that.