# Entity Framework Entity properties as Object type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I have multiple DB versions that I cannot change. I have readonly MVC application with EF attached to those DB on different environments. 
I have encountered a problem when entity property datatypes just don't match and Entity Framework throws datatype mismatch exception. 
What I've done is created property type of object and mapped a column in a DB then added to original generated column "Passed" and skipped mapping, added getter with object to Int32? conversion. Property "_passed" gets always null sadly.

Maybe anyone have an idea how to solve object to Int32 conversion problem or point me to a direction to a more correct approach regarding this issue?

Thanks,
E

```
[Table("VotingSession")]
public partial class VotingSession
{

    [Column("Passed")]
    public object _passed;
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Agenda_id { get; set; }

    public double? TotalLoggedIn { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public object Passed {
        get
        {
            if (_passed.GetType() == typeof(bool))
            {
               return (bool)_passed == true ? 1 : 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return _passed;
            }
        }

    }

    [NotMapped]
    public int? Quorum { get; set; }
```

Comment: what? data type in the database is column `[Column("Passed")]` also you made it private so EF db wont see it... so its quite confusing was to what you are trying to do...

Comment: The problem is that I have one web application for a database that is used on other system. That system has different versions of DB, that means some of the entities differs. As my solution is db first, i'm generating entities from one DB and it doesn't fit to other versions

Comment: I see, mmm you not gona like the answer... but the only way i see this working is creating different contexts for each Db instance.. and have the correct type on each. No matter how you try this in your current context i don't see it working.

Comment: Having different contexts makes deployment very complicated and that is the reason I want to have a "universal" solution for all databases I have

Comment: `"universal" solution for all databases`, would be to have different contexts in this situation, As i'm suggesting that i do not think it is possible to do what you are trying to. `deployment very complicated` they should not be, you could work to simplify that part. Without more information of how and why you have things setup the way you have, its hard to suggest/recommend anything. Google EF dynamic property. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458802/dynamic-property-binding-in-ef` basically saying the same as me.

Comment: I would try the string thing.... that may be a solution if it works. In the comments in the link i provided above.

Comment: Changing to string didn't worked.

Comment: Having different contexts doesn't solve my problems. It means that every time when I need to deploy an application dbcontexts have to be regenerated manually. Otherwise type mismatch excteptions will be firing and application will be crashing because of field datatype inconsistency.

Comment: I'm just trying to help ....`It means that every time when I need to deploy an application dbcontexts have to be regenerated manually.` doesn't make sense.. config when you deploy? nothing manual.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use backing field for db first models, 
you can try to do this, 
Override getter, if typeof the model.Passed is bool, check if true return 1 else 0, if not bool, return this.Passed value;

```
public object Passed {
    get
    {
        if (this.Passed.GetType() == typeof(bool))
        {
           return this.Passed == true ? 1 : 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Passed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That thing fires stackoverflow exception, sadly

Comment: it is sad, I am sorry